# A point between two charges has an electric potential of zero, but a charge placed at this point will gain kinetic energy. Why?

Tags: electric-fields

If I have a positive charge of +q and a negative charge of -q that are set a distance of r apart from each other, their midpoint will have an electric potential of zero. However, if I put a test charge into this midpoint and release it, it will gain kinetic energy, and I am under the impression that it comes from some sort of potential energy. But according to my book, that midpoint that it was placed at has no potential? Where does the kinetic energy come from?

Comment: Your mistake is in assuming that if the potential is zero, then no work can be done on a point there; this is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual value of the potential is not meaningful, what is meaningful is the gradient: the field on a particle is given by $\vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla} V$. Equivalently, what is meaningful is only the potential **difference** between 2 points.

Notice that one can define a new potential differing from the old by an additive constant: $V' = V + c$ and the force will still be the same. So we have a redundancy in the system when describing potential energy, this is a gauge degree of freedom. But nevermind the jargon for now.

In your case, the test charge (positive)'s derivative of its potential energy will give rise to a force towards the negative charge, and so it moves towards the negative charge. Conservation of energy holds, and the gain in KE must be compensated by a loss (i.e. difference) of PE.

The potential being $0$ at the midpoint is a consequence of choosing $c$ such that the potential at the point $r\to \infty$ has $V \to 0 $, but one can equally well define the potential at $\infty$ to be $1$ GeV, for example, and nothing physical would change.

Comment: Does the fact that the potential for that point is zero mean that a charge placed at the point will have zero potential energy? If not, then what is the significance of calculating such a value?

Comment: As all that matters is potential difference. One can define any point as being the zero of the potential. Similarly, the electrical potential energy of the charge is therefore only meaningful relative to some other point in the system.

Comment: @ByronS To reiterate the point. When you say 'this object has $X$ PE', you really mean 'this object has $X$ PE with respect to some special point in the system'. Teachers / books which don't state this point ought to be spanked. Usually the 'special point' is taken to be the point at infinity and the potential set to 0 there.

Comment: So when we calculate the potential difference at a location due to an electric field emitted by ONE point charge, is it the difference in potential at the charge's location, and a point that is infinitely far from the charge?

Comment: @ByronS Not quite, not the charge's location. We say that we calculate the potential due to to an electric field of a point charge at point $r$ by taking another test charge which starts all the way at infinity and then bringing it to a point $r$ infinitesimally slowly. This then just measures the potential difference between infinity and $r$ which we say is the potential of the point charge at distance $r$.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Just one last question. In my example in the initial question where we have two point charges, the potential difference determines how much potential energy the placed test charge has, right? Which difference is it that determines this potential energy. This confuses me since we have 3 charges, and the location of the test charge matters.

Comment: @ByronS The two charges (or any collection of charges) will create a potential field that permeates all space. A test charge put into this system will acquire a potential energy, due to this potential field, of strength $q V$, as measured from the potential energy at infinity, $0$.